# How to insert javascript function into html div

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I have a .cshtml file with the following in the head tag:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    getPlatform = function() {
   if (Platform.Android) {
    return "androidlink";
   }
   else if (Platform.IOS) {
    return "IOSLink";
   }
   else {
    return "other";
   }
    }
</script>
```

The reason I've inserted this is because this logic was already taken care of in another javascript file which I've imported in. Essentially what I need to do is change the link of a button depending on which platform the user is using. I've tried the following but this does not work (and even if it did, looks messy and I'm sure incorrect) but I can't seem to find a solution. Can anyone help please?

```
</div>
  <a href=<script type="text/javascript">getPlatform()</script> id="mobilelink" class="btn" </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot write this:
`<a href=<script type="text/javascript">getPlatform()</script> id="mobilelink" class="btn" </a>`

This is how it can be done:

```
</div>
  <a href="" id="mobilelink" class="btn" </a>
</div>

<!-- Later in the page (ideally just before the end </body> tag) -->

<script>
document.getElementById('mobileLink).href = getPlatform()
function getPlatform  () {
  if (Platform.Android) {
      return "androidlink";
  }
  else if (Platform.IOS) {
      return "IOSLink";
  }
  else {
      return "other";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you check it when the page is loaded and change the href of the a tag accordingly? Like:

```
<a id = "mobileLink" href="">some text</a>
```

And

```
var getPlatform = function() {
      if (Platform.Android) {
          return "androidlink";
      }
      else if (Platform.IOS) {
          return "IOSLink";
      }
      else {
          return "other";
      }
    }
document.getElemenyById("mobileLink").href = getPlatform
//Or innerHTML, I don't really understand what you want to do
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         function getPlatform() {
          if (Platform.Android) {
              document.getElementById('mobileLink').innerhtml = "androidlink";
          }
          else if (Platform.IOS) {
              document.getElementById('mobileLink').innerhtml = "IOSLink";
          }
          else {
              document.getElementById('mobileLink').innerhtml = "other";
          }
        }
    </script>
```

the html,

```
</div id="mobilelink" class="btn" onload = "getPlatform()">
</div>
```

Right now I can only assume the results, that you need. This is one of the ways, inwhich you can return the result from a JS function to the html division. If the onload doesnt work, I'd suggest using an `onclick = "getPlatform()"` function since that is more aggressive in its notation.

Answer (score 0):

this is incorrect approach.
I would recommend you put all scripts before closer `</body>` html-tag.
Then in your script you can write such code like:

```js
const platform = getPlatform();
const mobilelinkEl = document.querySelector('#mobilelink');
mobilelinkEl.setAttribute("src", platform);
```

Make sure, that your script tag with `src` attribute set placed after script tag with `getPlatform`, and also make sure you have access to `getPlatform` function.

If you'll have additional question, write comments, I'll try to help you.